# In pandas, how to groupby and apply/transform on each whole group (NOT aggregation)?

Tags: python, pandas

I've looked into agg/apply/transform after groupby, but none of them seem to meet my need.
Here is an example DF:

```
df_seq = pd.DataFrame({
    'person':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Lucy', 'Lucy', 'Lucy'],
    'day':[1,2,3,1,4,6],
    'food':['beef', 'lamb', 'chicken', 'fish', 'pork', 'venison']
})

person,day,food
Tom,1,beef
Tom,2,lamb
Tom,3,chicken
Lucy,1,fish
Lucy,4,pork
Lucy,6,venison
```

The `day` column shows that, for each `person`, he/she consumes food in sequential orders.

**Now I would like to group by the `person` col, and create a DataFrame which contains food pairs for two neighboring days/time (as shown below)**.

***Note the `day` column is only for example purpose here so the values of it should not be used***. *It only means the `food` column is in sequential order. In my real data, it's a datetime column.*

```
person,day,food,food_next
Tom,1,beef,lamb
Tom,2,lamb,chicken
Lucy,1,fish,pork
Lucy,4,pork,venison
```

At the moment, I can only do this with a for-loop to iterate through all users. It's very slow.

Is it possible to use a groupby and apply/transform to achieve this, or any vectorized operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new column by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and then remove rows with missing values in `food_next` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = (df_seq.assign(food_next = df_seq.groupby('person')['food'].shift(-1))
            .dropna(subset=['food_next']))
print (df)
  person  day  food food_next
0    Tom    1  beef      lamb
1    Tom    2  lamb   chicken
3   Lucy    1  fish      pork
4   Lucy    4  pork   venison
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I didn't know this function `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift
` exists...

Comment: My for-loop solution takes 17 mins and your solution takes only 1 s! :D

Answer (score 0):

This might be a slightly patchy answer, and it doesn't perform an aggregation in the standard sense.

First, a small querying function that, given a name and a day, will return the first result (assuming the data is pre-sorted) that matches the parameters, and failing that, returns some default value:

```
def get_next_food(df, person, day):
    results = df.query(f"`person`=='{person}' and `day`>{day}")
    if len(results)>0:
        return results.iloc[0]['food']
    else:
        return "Mystery"
```

You can use this as follows:

```
get_food(df_seq,"Tom", 1)

> 'lamb'
```

Now, we can use this in an `apply` statement, to populate a new column with the results of this function applied row-wise:

```
df_seq['next_food']=df_seq.apply(lambda x : get_food(df_seq, x['person'], x['day']), axis=1)

>
  person  day     food next_food
0    Tom    1     beef      lamb
1    Tom    2     lamb   chicken
2    Tom    3  chicken   Mystery
3   Lucy    1     fish      pork
4   Lucy    4     pork   venison
5   Lucy    6  venison   Mystery
```

Give it a try, I'm not convinced you'll see a vast performance improvement, but it'd be interesting to find out.